# How do I add timezone configuration to my environment.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

First, what is the difference between configuring in my application.rb file vs. my environment.rb file?

I read that I need to configure my timezone default in my environment.rb file. I am not quite sure how to do that though. So far I have this in my environment.rb file:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
SampleApp::Application.initialize!
```

Do I need to rerun the rails server after make changes? Any additional steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In rails 2, it was environment.rb that had all the configuration. In rails 3 it's changed to application.rb, as well as environment/production.rb and environment/development.rb, and Gemfile. To configure timezone, put this in application.rb in the Application class:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end
```

You can run `rake time:zones:all` to see a list of available timezones.

**edit** In rails 3 you don't need to touch environment.rb.

Answer (score 2):

From [The Rails (3) Initialization Process](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html):

> 1.14 config/environment.rb
>
> > This file is the common file required by config.ru (rails server) and Passenger. This is where these two ways to run the server meet; everything before this point has been Rack and Rails setup.
> >
> > This file begins with requiring config/application.rb.
>
> 1.15 config/application.rb
>
> > This file requires config/boot.rb, but only if it hasn’t been required before, which would be the case in rails server but wouldn’t be the case with Passenger.
> >
> > Then the fun begins!

To configure your application's timezone, add this to your application.rb:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  # ...

  config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)' # for example

  # ...
end
```

And, as @bricker points out, `rake time:zones:all` displays all available timezones.